# How do I overlay vector data over a 3D terrain basemap?

Tags: qgis, basemap, terrain

I would like to create a map that is similar to the one found here: https://www.reddit.com/r/MapPorn/comments/lpo557/geological_map_of_north_america/ .

I'm thinking that you could replicate this with a transparent terrain basemap and add the appropriate layers on top of this. However, I am also open to other suggestions if anyone has better ideas on repeating this style of map.

---

Edit after everyone's feedback:
[image]

Comment: You'll obviously have to provide a little more details on what you are trying to achieve and witch which data actually. Your question is a little vague in its current state. Also, trying to show and share what you already did is a golden way to getting a precise answer. ;-)

Comment: that's a 3 d rendering, you need the terrain, the other layers are "draped" over the dem, and also you need a light source, i think it's really achievable in qgis

Comment: Perhaps something like this https://www.geodose.com/2020/02/how-to-make-beautiful-hillshading-map-qgis.html.

Comment: geology maps for GIS software can be used from https://ngmdb.usgs.gov/gmna/

Comment: Okay so I have an update. Thanks for the quick feedback. I used a DEM file I had in my files of Death Valley and the geology data that @Mapperz suggested and was able to repeat it on a small scale. However, the lighting is still a little off and if fixed could really sell the 3D feel of it. In summary, I created a hillshade of the DEM and then "burned" in the geology dataset with about 40% opacity.